# Why calling SP with parameters to return multiple resultsets in Entity Framework throws error

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which has 2 input parameters and returns **multiple** **result** set.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetList]
    @eid int,
    @sid int,

    AS 

SELECT ID, NAME FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE id=@eid;

SELECT ID, NAME FROM STUDENTS WHERE id=@sid
```

In entity framework I am calling this **stored procedure as below.**

I am using this tutorial from msdn.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj691402(v=vs.113).aspx

```
using (var db = new APIContext()) {

                db.Database.Initialize(force: false);
                var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[sp_GetList]";

                DbParameter eid = cmd.CreateParameter();
                eid.ParameterName = "@eid";
                eid.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int32;
                eid.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                eid.Value = resourceID;

                DbParameter sid = cmd.CreateParameter();
                sid.ParameterName = "@sid";
                sid.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Date;
                sid.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                sid.Value = sid;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(sid);

                try
                {
                    db.Database.Connection.Open();
                    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    EmpList = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
                        .ObjectContext
                        .Translate<Shared.Model.EmpList>(reader).ToList();

                    MList.EmpList = EmpList;


                    reader.NextResult();
                    SList = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
                        .ObjectContext
                        .Translate<Shared.Model.SList>(reader).ToList();

                    MList.SList = SList;


                }
                finally
                {
                    db.Database.Connection.Close();
                }
```

When I run this code, I get error:

```
Additional information: Procedure or function 'sp_GetList' expects parameter '@eid', which was not supplied.
```

I understand this is very basic error when it comes to ado.net, but this is different using Entity framework.

Any help is apreciated.

Comment: @sid is declared as an "date" and used as an int later in the DB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems to be missing:

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add(eid);
```

Comment: I can't believe, I made this silly mistake. Thank you for pointing it out.